# I want to see which records are returned when count > 1 in access 2010

Tags: ms-access-2010

I'm admittedly new to access so forgive me if there is a simple solution. I have had difficulty searching for an answer as I'm not sure how this needs to be worded...

I have a database containing hundreds of thousands of invoices. I have a query that searches for invoices of the same amount on the same day by the same vendor (with different invoice numbers).

I group by this criteria as well as a count > 1 to display possible duplicates. I'd like to see each record displayed, but it only shows the first invoice number since if I were to group by invoice, the count would be 1 and nothing would get pulled..

I'm sure there is a better way of doing this to achieve the results that I want,. But I am at a loss. If there is further information required to assist, I'll provide what I can.

Thank you.

Comment: You have to show us your sql query.

Comment: I'm currently using the design view since I'm fairly new to all this. Is this something that will need to be completed through SQL view?

Comment: If you have no more than a count of two, you can include `Min(InvoiceNumber)` and `Max(InvoiceNumber)` in your query.

Comment: Use `View | SQL View` and edit your question to copy/paste the SQL in between code tags

Comment: In Design View you could join to the same Invoice table using join on Amount, Date, Vendor, then add one field Invoice Number from first table, with criteria being `<> InvoiceTable2.InvoiceNumber`